# Blue color filter for Ubuntu with multiple screen support

Tags: ubuntu, display

I am looking for software which helps me reduce the blue light on multiple screens on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I tried Redshift and Flux but unfortunately they don't have support for multiple screens.

Comment: does the "night mode" built in to Ubuntu work for multiple monitors?

Comment: in my configuration where I used DisplayLink, it is not working and this is DisplayLink fault unfortunatelly

Comment: That would be an important thing to add to your question, since normally most options should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this is a defect in the DisplayLink drivers, and is just not possible. As an alternative, you can try changing the RGB settings on your monitor, see [here](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/520)

Comment: Yes, my apologize, I should have added it to the question but at the beginning I didn't realize that DisplayLink can cause the problem. Thanks for pointing out